# How to make validation appear but jquery form to not appear

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have validation working, so when a user doesn't enter a reference number and clicks search the validation message appears, but so does the form. The form is empty because there was nothing put into the input field.

I want the validation message to appear but not the form when ever the user clicks search. In other words the user cannot do anything until they type in a valid reference number. This is my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').on('click', (function(event) {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') {
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
      $('#summary').hide();
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();
    };
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> <span class="errorMsg">Reference number 
  required</span>
  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
</form>

<form id="summary" method="get" action="">
  <h2>Summary Form</h2>
  //form content is here
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#summary').hide();
     $('#search').on('click', (function(event) {
     if ($('#ref').val() == '') { 
     $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
         $('#summary').hide();
     } else {
         $('#summary').show();
         $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();
     };
     }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works however when the validation message appears the search button disappears. Previously I had the jquery hide() method on the search button so that when they click the search button it would disappear and the form would appear. Is there any way I can keep the search button until the right reference number is added

Comment: If you want to disable the button use $("#search").attr('disabled','disabled'); in the if  and $("#search").removeAttr('disabled'); in the else block

Answer (score 0):

I would take it a bit further and disable the submit button as well.

The following will run your check on keyup (so anytime a new character is entered) and also on change (this is detected when the field value is changed when it's lost focus).

You'll also notice that the event listener is bound to the input now and not the submit button since we're disabling it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ref').on('keyup change',function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).next('.errorMsg').show();
      $("#search").attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
      $('#summary').hide();
      $(this).next('.errorMsg').hide();
      $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
    };
  });
  $(this).next('.errorMsg').show(); // show initially. Not necessary but OP was having a conflicting style.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12">
  <span class="errorMsg">Reference number required</span>
  <button type="button" id="search" disabled>Search</button>
</form>

<form id="summary" method="get" action="">
  <h2>Summary Form</h2>
  //form content is here
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any way my validation message can come up as well as the search button being disabled?

Comment: Yes sorry I am talking about the span class

Comment: No I don't see any error message, I think it is because the search button is disabled so the error message wont appear?  I am using chrome, and there is no errors in the console.

Comment: Yea I know so am I, no I am not seeing it at all. When I try click the button nothing happens (because it is disabled) but then when I add a reference number in the correct data appears. But no error message is appearing